# Choose Pivot in Quicksort

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am learning quick sort. I am not quiet understand how to choose pivot..

Assume I have a list of: [15, 5, 4, 18, 12, 19, 14, 10, 8, 20]
If I choose the pivot of 19, will the two lists for the next call be [15,5,4,18,12,14,10,8], [20]?

Comment: There is no strict rule about how to choose the pivot. Taking the middle of the first 3 numbers can do the job but it depends on the distribution of your list. If you choose 19, then indeed the two lists would be as you describe.

Comment: Yes, list contents is correct, but element order might change.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you choose 19 as your pivot then those will be the two sublists created. Usually, quicksort requires a way of choosing the pivot which is consistent throughout your sort. Some might say pick the first, middle, or last element of your list.